# Interface in Sharepoint 2013, backend in PHP

Tags: 2013, php

I want to create an application which has the **interface** as a **Sharepoint 2013 page** (for example a number of `input` and `select` elements within a Script Editor), but for the operations with the data in the fields I want to use **php** with a **mysql** database.

How can I do that?